# Java JKS files read from resource dir Keystore Exceptions

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, ssl-client-authentication

I copied the keystore.jks & cacerts files into the restapi project under src/main/resources. And facing the below exception.

But when i try to read keystore.jks & cacerts files from linux path[ instead of reading from resources dir ] it works.

Exception :

```
Reading the Certificate file from resource dir...file:/home/raam/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/webapps/SampleRestApi/WEB-INF/classes/keystore.jks
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=53, too big.
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:169)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1804)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:195)
        at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:102)
        at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:716)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at com.test.api.utils.HttpCilentUtil.getHttpsClient(HttpCilentUtil.java:94)
        at com.test.api.utils.HttpCilentUtil.auditLogPost(HttpCilentUtil.java:33)
        at com.test.api.BalanceServiceImpl.auditLog(BalanceServiceImpl.java:37)
        at com.test.api.BalanceServiceImpl.getBalance(BalanceServiceImpl.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=53, too big.
        at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:599)
        at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:252)
        at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.readVector(DerInputStream.java:424)
        at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getSequence(DerInputStream.java:332)
        at sun.security.x509.X500Name.parseDER(X500Name.java:793)
        at sun.security.x509.X500Name.<init>(X500Name.java:306)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:649)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:167)
        ... 55 more
29-Aug-2019 17:21:56.204 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
        java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.test.api.utils.HttpCilentUtil.auditLogPost(HttpCilentUtil.java:77)
                at com.test.api.BalanceServiceImpl.auditLog(BalanceServiceImpl.java:37)
                at com.test.api.BalanceServiceImpl.getBalance(BalanceServiceImpl.java:30)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
                at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
                at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
                at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
                at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Below is the code I am trying to run by reading the jks files from resources dir.

```
public class HttpCilentExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpCilentExample client = new HttpCilentExample();
        client.post();
    }


    public void post() throws IOException {
        String url = "https://localhost:8080/listener";
        CloseableHttpClient client = null;
        try {
            client = getHttpsClient();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("URL :" + url);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            pojoClass pojo1 = new pojoClass();
            pojo1.setUsername("Hello" + new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(pojo1));
            post.setEntity(postingString);
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            client.close();
        }
    }

    class pojoClass {
        private String username;

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
    }

    public CloseableHttpClient getHttpsClient() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        String keystore_loc = "keystore.jks";
        String password = "password123";
        String truststore_loc = "cacerts";

        CloseableHttpClient returnHttpclient = null;
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(getFile(keystore_loc));
        keyStore.load(instream, password.toCharArray());
        int timeout = 90000;
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(timeout).setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout).setSocketTimeout(timeout).build();

        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, password.toCharArray()).loadTrustMaterial(
                getFile(truststore_loc), password.toCharArray(), new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[]{"TLSv1.2"}, null,
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        returnHttpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();

        return returnHttpclient;
    }

    public File getFile(String fileName) {
        URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(fileName);

        if (resource == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File is not available under resource dir !");
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileName + " : Reading the Certificate file from resource dir..." + resource);
            return new File(resource.getFile());
        }
    }

}
```

But When I read like below, it works. Any suggestions, please.

```
FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/rvp/keys/keystore.jks"));
```

Comment: You have corrupted the KeyStore between creation and embedding in the WAR file. This is anyway not a good solution. You want the KeyStore outside the webapp where it can be updated separately.

Comment: okay. Sorry, I am new to this SSL concepts, what do you mean by " it can be updated separately". I am not updating any files. I just want to read the .jks files and authenticate httpS POST call

Comment: You need to update the JKS files as and when certificates expire or are rekeyed. Certificates aren't part of the application, they are part of the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied key-store have wrong line break for destination OS.

Comment: okay, if this is the case, then any solution to fix...     Like I am coping the jks files from Linux to window eclipse project, once after packaging it on windows, deployed it on tomcat running on Linux machine.

Comment: No it doesn't. Keystores don't have line breaks. They are binary files. Possibly it was copied as a text file, in which case the solution is 'don't'.

Comment: can you try building your project in eclipse with linux line delimiter? Preference->workspace->select new text file line delimiter as Linux

Comment: The line delimiter is irrelevant. It's not a text file. Read what I wrote.

Comment: @Mukesh if I set Linux line delimiter in eclipse/IntelliJ. How can I make sure the same while packing it as a WAR file?

Comment: you can try to generate checksum/hash for the keystore and compare original (linux) vs in your tomcat after deployment. Example: sha1sum keystore.jks

Comment: @RaAm This is all irrelevant. We already know the keystore is corrupt. It is already failing, so of course it will also fail a checksum test. The solution has nothing whatsoever to do with text files or ther line terminators. There *are* no line terminators, because there are no lines, because it isn't a text file. This has already been stated about five times now. The solution is to not corrupt it during whatever copy steps are involved.

Comment: @user207421 Okay. then let me see the alternatives. Thanks for your inputs.